# Error while using Newtonsoft.Json to parse a Json string

Tags: json, parsing, json.net

My JSON string looks like this. Please note that it has escape characters.

```
string json = "\"{\\\"Status\\\":true,\\\"ID\\\":24501}\"";
```

When I use the Parse method like below I run into an error stated below:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
```

Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current `JsonReader` item is not an object: `String`

How do I get rid of this error or is there any other method to parse my json string and fetch the values?

Comment: no answer of this, m facing the same prob

Answer (score 4):

Remove first and last quotes:

```
string json = "{\"Status\":true,\"ID\":24501}";
```

See the Json format [here](http://www.json.org/).

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your object is double encoded. Try:

```
string json = "{\"Status\":true,\"ID\":24501}";
```

Comment: That json string is what I get from an API. How do I remove the escape characters?\

Comment: @SVI : I'm late to the party but if anybody needs it, just replace them using something like `json.Replace("\\\\", "\\")`

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this

```
json = json.Replace(@"\", string.Empty).Trim(new char[]{'\"'})
```

Answer (score 0):

in here format should be something like this:

```
string jsonNew = @"{'Status': True,'ID': 24501 }";
```

Answer (score 0):

As SolarBear says in his comment, the problem is double-escaping.

To get the proper format, like this:

```
string json = "{\"Status\":true,\"ID\":24501}";
```

Do something like this:

```
json = json.Replace("\\\\", "\\");
```

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue today. My solution to this is contained in this extension method (using `c#`):

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string RemoveDoubleEncoding(this string text)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            return string.Empty;
        var result = text.TrimStart('\"').TrimEnd('\"');
        result = result.Replace(@"\", string.Empty);
        return result;
    }
}
```